# Numerical lists to field-delimited string with Elisp

Tags: string, list, elisp, delimiter

I have a requirement where i'd like to generate a comma-separated sequence of numbers with elisp (i want to be able to generate this from within emacs).

Am creating the sequence with

`(setq ls (number-sequence 0 5 1))`

Now I want to convert this to list of strings so that I may do something like

`(s-join "," ls_strings)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The builtin function `mapconcat` is commonly used for this, eg.

```
(mapconcat 'number-to-string (number-sequence 0 5 1) ",")
```

Answer (score 0):

How about...

`(s-join "," (mapcar #'number-to-string ls))`?

Here's a simple function. Should work as long as your input arguments are well-formed.

```
(defun my/join-list-with (separator lst) 
    (s-join separator (mapcar #'number-to-string lst)))

(my/join-list-with "," '(0 1 2 3 4 5))
"0,1,2,3,4,5"
```